# can't overwrite the env values from docker run

Tags: node.js, docker, environment-variables

I have a dockerfile where I have web build and api build and I need a web build arg which needs to be overwritten later at the runtime. When I do as below then it does override as I see new value passed at the runtime in the printenv but when the url is called it still shows the old build value. Here is the Dockerfile:

```
# base
# ------------------------------------------------
FROM node:18-bookworm-slim as base
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN  yarn install


# api build
# ------------------------------------------------
FROM base as api_build
RUN yarn prisma generate

# web build
# ------------------------------------------------
FROM base as web_build

# Add web environment variables here as args
ARG ENV1=val1
RUN yarn  build web --no-prerender

# serve api
# ------------------------------------------------
FROM node:18-bookworm-slim as serve

#Add runtime envs here
ENV ENV1=${ENV1}
ENV NODE_ENV=production
USER node
WORKDIR /home/node/app
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn add api-server web-server
EXPOSE 8910
CMD ["sh", "-c", "node_modules/.bin/rw-server api & node_modules/.bin/rw-server web"]
```

I run following command to run the image after bulding
docker run -e ENV1="val2"  -dt -p 8910:8910 imagename

WHen I do docker exec and check the printenv then I can see the updated value but when I run the webapp and the ENV1 value is the redirect url the it uses the val1 from the build argument rather then the val2 from the environment variable

Comment: you would need to check the documentation of the web framework you are using. For example nextjs has a set of env vars prefixed with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` the docs https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#runtime-environment-variables. State that these vars are set at build time, and even if you change them later at rune time it wont have any effect `o expose an environment variable to the browser, it must be prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC_. However, these public environment variables will be inlined into the JavaScript bundle during next build.`

Comment: So it could be that your framework is taking the values at build time and baking them into the javascript or build files, so even though you change them after and you can see in the container they have updated values, the build files probably are already compiled with the values from before.

Comment: Thank you @ChrisDoyle , I am going to refer the doc about the framework here
https://redwoodjs.com/docs/environment-variables and see if I can resolve it.

Comment: The docs page you linked says exactly that `Redwood also configures Vite, so that all references to process.env vars on the Web side will be replaced with the variable's actual value at build-time.`

Comment: Essentially whats happening here is that when you run the build process, the web app is looking up the env vars at that point, and is then building and embedding those values into the js code. So in the next stage and when your running the container changing those env vars has not effect as they are not read when the container starts, they were processed at the build stage and embeded in the JS.

Comment: Also I was not able to run the docker when I had this in the CMD 
CMD [ "node_modules/.bin/rw-server", "--load-env-files", "&&", "node_modules/.bin/rw-web-server" ]  
as I was getting error that --load-env-file is not valid arugument so not sure if that is causing some error to load the env variables as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem here is that `ARG` variables are not automatically available in subsequent stages. They are only accessible within the stage they are defined. If you want it to work in the final stage then you need to duplicate it there.

Consider this stripped down version of `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:18-bookworm-slim as base

# ------------------------------------------------

FROM base as api_build

# ------------------------------------------------

FROM base as web_build

ARG ENV1=val1

# ------------------------------------------------

FROM node:18-bookworm-slim as serve

ARG ENV1=val1
ENV ENV1=${ENV1}

CMD echo $ENV1
```

The `ARG` is being redeclared in the `serve` stage.

Build and run with neither build nor environment variables.

```
docker build -t arg-env . && docker run -it arg-env
```

The value of `ENV1` is set to the default provided to `ARG` in the `Dockerfile`.

[image]

Use a build argument.

```
docker build --build-arg ENV1="val2" -t arg-env . && docker run -it arg-env
```

The value of `ENV1` is now set at build time.

[image]

Specify an environment variable at run time.

```
docker build -t arg-env . && docker run -it -e ENV1=val3 arg-env
```

This will override the build time setting. You'll get the same outcome here regardless of whether or not you specify a `--build-arg` because the environment variable is being set at run time with `-e`.

[image]

Comment: docker compose run -e     did you use this cmd

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. The OP was not using Docker Compose. And, yes, I did use `-e` (see last step). The key here is the distinction between build arguments (build time) and environment variables (run time).

Comment: I can see the updated value of the environment variable in the docker container runtime as I see the value that was passed with docker run but for some reason it is not being used and for some reason it seems to be baked in the docker build so going to check the framework document as suggested above and see if I can find something. 
https://redwoodjs.com/docs/environment-variables

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are actually wanting to do then. Do you want the value of `ENV1` to also change in the `web_build` stage? Could you please be clear about what you are trying to achieve?